# Carousel doesn't work bootstrap 5. Someone can help me?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, bootstrap-5

Someone can help me? I'm using bootstrap carousel in my webpage but carousel doesn't work. What is the reason? Does it need something extra for it to work?

```
<div class="container">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="aşağı-kısım-carousel-slide carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="{{asset('/img/manzara.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{asset('/img/manzara.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{asset('/img/manzara.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is from:

1. or to the class (you changed the name of the class)
2. or bootstrap files you may have inserted incorrectly.

Try to execute this code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/SONATA-hero-option1-764A5360-edit.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/1200x0/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5d35eacaf1176b0008974b54%2F0x0.jpg%3FcropX1%3D790%26cropX2%3D5350%26cropY1%3D784%26cropY2%3D3349" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-73268134,width-640,resizemode-4,imgsize-35417/surprise-heard-of-a-sony-car.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and carousel worked. I changed class again and worked. Most likely due to incorrectly inserted code.

Comment: I wonder if inserted cdn version 4.0.0 is OK for bootstrap 5 according to the topic title and tag?